# average of the sum outputted in while loop with python

Tags: python, while-loop

I don't know why I'm having so much trouble with this. I need to get the average of the sum that is outputted from def main():. I have tried to put the average within the def main and tried to use a separate def. both ways do not come out as expected.

Below is where I am at currently.

```
def main():
    totalMiles = 0
    dayTotal = 0
    mileageGoal = eval(
        input("How many miles would you like to run this week? "))
    while totalMiles != mileageGoal:
        dailyTotal = eval(
            input(f"How many miles did you run on day {dayTotal + 1}? "))
        totalMiles = totalMiles + dailyTotal
        dayTotal = dayTotal + 1
        if totalMiles >= mileageGoal:
            print("You hit your goal! Keep going!")
            print(f"You ran {totalMiles} miles!")
            print(f"You completed your goal in {dayTotal} days! Congratulations!")
            break


main()


def average():
    average = totalMiles / dayTotal
    return average
    print('the average miles you ran was:', average)
```

Comment: What are you trying to return from the main function?

Answer (score 0):

after I posted this question I tried a different path which work.

'''

```
def main():
    totalMiles = 0
    dayTotal = 0
    mileageGoal = eval(
        input("How many miles would you like to run this week? "))
    while totalMiles != mileageGoal:
        dailyTotal = eval(
            input(f"How many miles did you run on day {dayTotal + 1}? "))
        totalMiles = totalMiles + dailyTotal
        dayTotal = dayTotal + 1
        if totalMiles >= mileageGoal:
            print("You hit your goal! Keep going!")
            print(f"You ran {totalMiles} miles!")
            print(
                f"You completed your goal in {dayTotal} days! Congratulations!")
            break
    average = totalMiles / dayTotal
    print('the average miles you ran was:', average)


main()
```

'''

although, if anyone has an easier way of going about this please post it. Anything helps!

Comment: Please make sure to check for logical errors in your code. In this question, the average functionn is never called. and it is unclear what or where are you returning something from main(). Also if you write somethhing after a rerturn statement in your code it is considered ass unreachable code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of what is called "scope". If you create a variable in a function, it will (normally) be "scoped" only to that function, so you can't access it from outside the function.

A simple fix would be to declare the variables as "global" that you need to use outside of the function: `global totalMiles`. But if you can avoid that, it is best to do so.

Your own fix to it is a good way to do it, just combining them into one function. But you could also have a function that returns a value, so you could return the total miles and day total from the function, assign it to a variable when you call it and then use that variable elsewhere in the code.